# Can I travel to Medellin with just my Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, schengen, indian-citizens, colombia

I am an Indian citizen and a Canadian Resident (PR). I just got my Schengen visa which is valid from Jan 30 - May 1.

I know Colombia admits Schengen visa holders from research.

Questions:

1. Could there be any issue/questions asked by French/Schengen immigration when I use the visa to actually enter Schengen? Regarding my use of visa to travel to Medellin?
2. Do officers generally allow Schengen visa holders, or is it on a case-by-case basis?
3. Anything else I should keep in mind while travelling to Medellin using my Schengen Visa?

Comment: I would be very surprised if Schengen border officers cared even for a second about your visits to Colombia based on a Schengen visa. However, you missed a condition for entry into Colombia with a Schengen visa: it must be valid for 180 days after your arrival date, which is definitely not the case here.

Answer (score 3):

> I know Colombia admits Schengen visa holders from research

Since your Schengen visa is only valid until 2024-05-01 (102 days at the time of writing), you do not fullfil the **minimum validity of 180 days at the time of entry to Colombia** condition.

> Could there be any issue/questions asked my French/Europe immigration when I use the visa actually enter Europe? Regarding my use of visa to travel to Medellin?

No, you must only fullfil the Schengen Area entry conditions.

---

> [List of countries | Chancellery](https://www.cancilleria.gov.co/tramites_servicios/visa/lista-a-b-c)
> (from [Quick visa guide | Chancellery - MINISTRY OF FOREIGN AFFAIRS](https://www.cancilleria.gov.co/en/procedures_services/visa/quick-visa-guide))
>
> - List C: Nationals of States with Conditional Visa Exemption for short stay
>   2. India
>
>   - Special cases of visa exemption
>     ... or if they are holders of a Schengen visa or a visa from the United States of America with a minimum validity of one hundred and eighty (180) days at the time of entry into the national territory.